# Binary-search tree vs hash table in terms of memory

Tags: algorithm, memory, binary-search-tree, hashtable

I have heard different things on the internet including someone clearly stating that BST requires less memory compared to hast tables, because hash tables acquire more memory at once than they need at the moment.

Can one tell me the pros and cons of each structure compared to the other only only it terms of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binary search tree is nothing but a linked list with 2 pointers per node. The memory required is of the order O(n) ,i.e., same as the number of elements stored in it.
A hash map on the other hand, is generally implemented as an array. So, there is some unused space on it always. Have a read here about how a hash map is implemented in java.: http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/

> HashMap is built on top of the array of Map.Entry objects. The
>   implementation ensures that this array length is always equal to at
>   least max( size, capacity ) / load_factor. Default load factor for
>   HashMap is 0.75 and default capacity is 16. Load factor specifies
>   which part of an array could be used for storage and is a value
>   between 0 and 1. The higher is the load factor, the less space is
>   being wasted, but HashMap starts to work slower due to increased rate
>   of collisions. The smaller if the load factor, the more memory is
>   wasted, but the performance of a HashMap is increasing due to smaller
>   possibility of collisions.